# Use an AWS IAM token to connect to a Postgres database using .pgpass

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Within our company we've the wish to connect to an AWS RDS postgres database based on a generated IAM token. Mostly, we use DBeaver to connect to databases. However, with DBeaver a .pgpass is necessary to make the connection.

My question how can we achieve the connection with DBeaver towards our AWS RDS database using the IAM token?

Thanks in advance!

Gr,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

You may be having issues due to not escaping the ':' char in the IAM token (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html for requirements).

I use the below powershell script to udpate .pgpass files for AWS Aurora and it works fine with DBeaver 22.2. Note the `$token = $token.Replace(':', '\:');` line. Script is basic but could to adapted to other use cases.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$hostname,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$database,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][int]$port=5432
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$region = $env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION;
if ($null -eq $region) {
    $region = "us-east-1";
}

$token = aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $hostname --port $port --region $region --username $username
if (!$?) { throw "failed to generate iam rds token"}
$token = $token.Replace(':', '\:');
$loc = $env:APPDATA + "\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
if ($null -eq $env:APPDATA) {
    $loc = $env:HOME + "/.pgpass";
} else {
    [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($env:APPDATA + "\postgresql");
}
$updated = "$($hostname):$($port):$($database):$($username):$token`n"
if (![IO.File]::Exists($loc)) {
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($loc, $updated);
    return;
}
$replaced = "";
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($loc))
{
    if ($line.ToLower().StartsWith($hostname.ToLower())) {
        $replaced += $updated
    } else {
        $replaced += $line + "`n";
    }
}
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($loc, $replaced);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried this and unfortunate it's not working as I then get FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user "x". Could be anything of course. If you receive the token it's also in the format host:port/Action&DBUser&SecurityToken&otherparams?

Comment: Are you connecting fine with other methods using the token? If not I'd check your IAM setup, `generate-db-auth-token` will create a token regardless of if the user is actually authorized to access the database / user but will fail on login attempt.

Comment: Via the psql command I got the same error, so that's at least consistent.. :p Thanks for your help so far, I'll check my IAM configs, but it's good to know that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to get DBeaver Community Edition working with [PostgreSQL PgPass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) and AWS IAM authentication:

```
% export AWS_REGION=us-east-2
% export RDSHOST=example.cluster-ro-abcde12345.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
% export RDSDBNAME=postgres
% export RDSUSER=skohrs
% echo "$RDSHOST:5432:$RDSDBNAME:$RDSUSER:$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 5432 --region $AWS_REGION --username $RDSUSER | sed 's/:/\\:/')" >> $HOME/.pgpass
```

DBeaver Connection Settings:
[image]